# overriding submit functions with content types

Tags: nodes, forms

I have created some content types, some are created programmatically, others (including the one I am interested in are where created using the front end GUI.

And this is where my issue starts, I would like to format some of the text that is returned on the form submit.

And to be honest i am unsure how to do this.

in this example I have created a custom content type called 'show_date'

I would think that when the subnit function is caled I can pass the data to a custom fucntion, I would imagine this to being called show_date_submit thus:

```
function show_date_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    /* 
     my custom code would go here
    */

}
```

Is this right? any help given is as always appreciated and given Thanks for.

Al the best,

Jim

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by using hook_form_alter, we can able to define a custom submit handler.

Find the form_id of that form and define a custom submit handler.

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'custom_add_user_form'){
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'show_date_submit_handler'; 
        //for submit $form['actions']['submit']  
        //for preview $form['actions']['preview']   
    }
}



function show_date_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state){
    // manipulate the form submitted values over here
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a very quick response, I will test and mark the post as answered

Comment: I think you might find problems with that - usually you need to target `$form['actions']['save']['#submit'][] = 'show_date_submit_handler';` or similar

Comment: Yes you are right @Clive. I have updated the assigning part of submit handler.

Comment: My mistake, it's `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']`